# How to read a pdf using itext library in android

Tags: android, itext

I am a newbie in android world. I tired to create a android project using eclipse IDE, in which i tried reading a pdf file with the help of itext library.
This pgm is not showing any output.Please tell me how to correct the code,so that i can extract the text from pdf file stored in Assets folder in the project.

The program code is given as :

```
public class hello extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static final String LOG_TAG="Fifth";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        AssetManager assetManager =getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        PdfReader reader=null;
        String str=null;
        int n=0;
        try {
            istr =(InputStream) assetManager.open("FirstPdf");


             reader=new PdfReader(istr);
             n=reader.getNumberOfPages();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"n value:" +n);
         str=reader.getPageContent(2).toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(n);
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

Regards
Thomas

Comment: What do you mean by the program is not showing any output? Is there an exception? Othewise the TextView tv should at least display 0?

Comment: @Roflcoptr its not showing anything.but in the console window ,task canceled is shown. Is this not the correct way to read a pdf?

Comment: Then there seams to be an exception. Are you're sure there isn't any? If there is it would be helpful if you post the exception.

Comment: [2011-01-04 18:33:47 - Fifth] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
[2011-01-04 18:33:47 - Fifth] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-01-04 18:33:47 - Fifth] Launch canceled!

Comment: Hi,who did you done then please provide me links i can also do it

Comment: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT means apk is failed to install on your device/emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short Answser

Not Supported!

#### Long Answer

Android's runtime isn't quite JME.  iText was never ported to JME in the first place.

Having said that, there are a couple iText->Android ports floating around.  But this has only been done by a few Knowledgeable Individuals who have ripped out large portions so they wouldn't have to port Everything to a subset-of-a-subset-plus-some-other-stuff that is the Android Runtime.

I understand that a port of iText Proper (the whole thing) is In The Works, but have no idea if it'll ever go anywhere, or when folks will be able to get their hands on it.

Answer (score 4):

try this

public class readPDF extends Activity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AssetManager assetManager =getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    PdfReader reader=null;
    String str=null;
    int n=0;
    try {
        istr = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.internals);

         reader=new PdfReader(istr);
         n=reader.getNumberOfPages();
         System.out.println("String"+str);
        Log.v("LOG:","n value:" +n);
     str=reader.getPageContent(2).toString();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(n));

}
```

}