# Android open pdf in my app no externals APIs

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-reader, pdf-rendering

I want to be able to read PDF in my App (e.g. in some LinearLayout) but I don't want to use anu external helpers, APIs. I have found PdfDocument and PdfRenderer objects, but they require such high API (21). Is any possibility to open a PDF file in my APP on low API level (10+) without external files?

And yes. I know it isn't so simple or short code, but for me it does no matter

Comment: have your phone has any reader installed?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use it. It's kind of writing own reader

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372484/how-to-create-our-own-pdf-viewer-for-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this library link will help to solve your problem.you can also search pdf library in androidarsenal.com

- https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library
- http://www.mupdf.com/

Answer (score -1):

If it does not matter and don´t want any external lib or API, you better program it yourself.

Comment: but it is not a problem for you... and don´t want to use external libs... I think you should upvote my answer

Comment: your anser didn't give me anything, I perfectly know I am to write it myself. I was asking how to. I stil don't know.